# How to get multiple input from one line in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to get multiple input from one line using ruby.
I know how to do it using Java.

```
        System.out.print("Enter three points for the triangle: ");
        double x1=  input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();
        double x3 = input.nextDouble();
        double y3 = input.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We'd like to see your attempt at writing the code in Ruby, sample input and expected output and any errors Ruby gave you, all in the body of the question. Without that it looks like you didn't try and are fishing for someone to write it for you, which isn't cool. See "[ask]" for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way would be to read one string, then split it into numbers. Something like this:

```
print "Enter three points for the triangle: "    
x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = gets.split.map(&:to_f)
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it, which helps keep SO neat and tidy as possible...

Comment: @Adlane: orde's comment was for you (in case you didn't get a red notification about it)